# Transparent CardView Child Shadow Does Not Appear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have a `CardView` with `cardBackgroundColor` set to Transparent. and `cardElevation` set to `3dp`

In the `CardView` it has an `ImageView`. I am wondering why there is no shadow on the `ImageView`.

Note: I purposely wrap the `ImageView` inside `CardView` to generate shadow on Pre Lollipop devices, but it doesn't seem to work.

Any idea please?

Comment: What happens, if you change your cardBackgroundColor to a different color? I think, how should something transparent throw a shadow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Set padding to parent view of card view to 3dp.

Like,
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:id="@+id/card1">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imgCard"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/add_contact" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvColor"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="Card View" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```